# Unable to install waterline_sqlite3 using npm

Tags: node.js, database, sails.js

i want to install waterlin_sqlite3 on sailsjs but im unable to install it on windows can anyone suggest me to install

npm -v:5.3.0
node -v: 6.11.0
attached screen shot of error which im getting in installation 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do:

```
npm install gulp -g
```

Then try again.

Whenever npm gives you trouble (it's gonna be often) you need to pay close attention to the output. In the screenshot you can see the error comes after "gulp" not being recognized.